# *ngFor performance is too slow

Tags: performance, angular

I have two arrays, One for the data 'data_list' and the second for the keys to retrieve data from the first one, My Issue here is that data_list contains 1900 rows and 20 fields for each row, Performance gets too slow and the page loads in about 20 seconds.

How can I improve the performance of this table?

```
<tbody>
           <tr *ngFor="let data of data_list;let last = last;let i = index;"  #FireJQuery>

                    <td class="width-percent-1 sorting_1" tabindex="0"></td>
                    <td *ngFor="let col of Descriptive_FieldsMap;let i = index;">

                     <div >
                         {{data[col.DBName] || 'N/A'}}
                     </div>
                 </td> 
              </tr>
        </tbody>
```

ts Code

```
this._bondServices.getBonds(this._localStorageService.get('userID').toString(), this.rulebookID, this._localStorageService.get('Project').toString())

                       .subscribe(
                           data_list => 
                           {
                               this.data_list = data_list;


                            }, //Bind to view
                            err => {
                                // Log errors if any
                                console.log(err);
                            },
                            () => {if(this.data_list) window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('bonds-ready'));});
```

}

Services.ts code

```
 return this._http.get(link)
                        .map((res:Response) => res.json()) // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
                        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

Comment: are you using promises or observables. update the post with typescript code as well

Comment: @Aravind I am using observables, Post Updated.

Comment: I often wonder when people ask questions like this;  What could you possibly be doing that you need to render 1900 rows of data on a web page?  It's unlikely that the user is going to read every line of data like that, and if you are instead generating it as a report you expect to be printed, there are reporting engines that are way more suited to this task....

Comment: @Claies Actually users can search for a specific data and filter those 1900 rows, also this table has paging so he will not read every line of data.

Comment: the table has filtering and paging?  why aren't you showing those here?  those are just as much a part of the entire rendering process as anything else that could affect performance.

Comment: @Claies Because I already removed them to test the performance, I am 100% percent sure It's because *ngFor, I removed all other thing it's a pure table with *ngFor as shown above.

Comment: well of course it's `*ngFor`, that code was never written to be optimized for the type of rendering you are trying to do.  Which is why you want to implement filtering and paging, to take the load off `*ngFor`.  but if you aren't showing how your filtering and paging are implemented, it's impossible to know if they are helping performance or not.  It sounds like they *aren't helping performance*, which would mean our best suggestions would be how to fix those features.

Comment: You can try to use `trackBy` option (https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.4.1/packages/common/src/directives/ng_for_of.ts#L75) and `ChangeDetectionStrategy` (https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy) and primitives instead `{{data[col.DBName] || 'N/A'}}`. Also you can use `linkViewContainerRef` (https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) instead `*ngFor`.